p-calendar issue with p-treeTable in angular
Below is my code snippet inside that i am facing issue.
<p-treeTable
  [columns]="cols"
  [value]="files"
  [resizableColumns]="true"
  [style]="{ width: '100%', overflow: 'auto!important' }"
  sortMode="multiple"
  [className]="'table nowrap w-100 dataTable no-footer'"
  [scrollable]="true"
  [tableStyle]="{ 'min-width': '50rem' }"
>
  <ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
    <colgroup>
      <col *ngFor="let col of columns" />
    </colgroup>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [ttSortableColumn]="col.field">
        {{ col.header }} <p-treeTableSortIcon [field]="col.field" />
      </th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template
    pTemplate="body"
    let-rowNode
    let-rowData="rowData"
    let-columns="columns"
    let-index="rowIndex"
  >
    <tr [ttRow]="rowNode">
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index" ttEditableColumn>
        <p-treeTableToggler [rowNode]="rowNode" *ngIf="i === 0" />
        <p-treeTableCellEditor>
          <ng-container [ngSwitch]="getColumnType(col)">
            <ng-template pTemplate="input" *ngSwitchCase="'text'">
              <input
                pInputText
                [ngClass]="{ 'editable-input': !col.readOnly }"
                (click)="handelClickEvent($event, rowData)"
                [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]"
                (focusout)="changeTextBoxValue(rowData, col.field)"
                placeholder="add task"
                [readonly]="isReadOnly(col)"
              />
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="input" *ngSwitchCase="'date'">
              <p-calendar
                appendTo="body"
                [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]"
                (click)="event.stopPropagation()"
                (ngModelChange)="
                  onDateChange(rowData, col.field);
                  inlineSaveTask(rowData, col.field)"
              ></p-calendar>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="input" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'">
              <p-dropdown
                appendTo="body"
                [options]="taskStatusList"
                [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]"
                (onChange)="onChangeDropDownValue($event, rowData, col.field)"
              />
            </ng-template>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-template pTemplate="output">
            {{ rowData[col.field] }}
          </ng-template>
        </p-treeTableCellEditor>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="action-buttons">
          <i
            *ngIf="rowData.id != '' && isShowAddTaskButton"
            class="fa fa-plus"
            aria-hidden="true"
            (click)="addSubTask(rowNode, rowData)"
          ></i>
          <i
            class="fa fa-trash"
            aria-hidden="true"
            (click)="deleteTask(rowData)"
          ></i>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-treeTable>


my angular and primeng version are as below
primeng: ^17.18.9,
@angular/cli: ^17.3.2,
Issue : Only Showing the current month dates not able to change month and year.
i did not add any date validation still it only showing me the current month when i try to switch the month from above given arrow it close the date picker. inside console i don't get any error.
